# Nested Hierarchy CSS Issue

Tags: html, css

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3h1hxy2w/4/

I'm trying to make a reusable set of CSS rules so that items under .ancestor class the first < l i>'s in .children groups would be visible, but their children would remain hidden.  The problem is it seems to travel down opening all 'children' groups.

First I close all of the children with display: none, then open any descendants of .ancestor

In this situation, I cannot add any helpful classes or use jQuery.  The current output is like this:

```
 Item One

    more items
            STUFF!
            more stuff
            even more stuff
        more items
        More items
    more items 2
        more items
        more items
        More items
    more items
        more items
        more items
        More items

Item Two

Item Three
```

but I'm shooting for

```
 Item One
    more items
            STUFF!
            more stuff
            even more stuff
        more items
        More items
    more items 2
    more items

Item Two

Item Three
```

Any ideas?

This is the html

```
 <ul id="hier">
  <li class="ancestor">
    Item One
      <ul class="children">
        <li class="ancestor">more items
              <ul class="children">
                <li class="ancestor current-parent">
                 Parent
                  <ul class="children">
                    <li class="current-cat">STUFF!</li>
                    <li>more stuff</li>
                    <li>even more stuff</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>More items</li>
              </ul>
        </li>
        <li>more items 2
              <ul class="children">
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>More items</li>
              </ul>
        </li>
        <li>more items
              <ul class="children">
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>More items</li>
              </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Item Two
      <ul class="children">
        <li>more items
              <ul class="children">
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>More items</li>
              </ul>
        </li>
        <li>more items
              <ul class="children">
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>More items</li>
              </ul>
        </li>
        <li>more items
              <ul class="children">
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>More items</li>
              </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
    <li>
    Item Three
      <ul class="children">
        <li>more items
              <ul class="children">
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>More items</li>
              </ul>
        </li>
        <li>more items
              <ul class="children">
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>More items</li>
              </ul>
        </li>
           <li>more items
              <ul class="children">
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>more items</li>
                <li>More items</li>
              </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

And here is the CSS so far

```
ul { list-style-type: none; }

 #hier li .children li { display: none; }

.ancestor .children li  { display: block !important;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul { list-style-type: none; }
.children li { display: none; }
.ancestor > .children > li { display: block; }
```

It is always important to avoid !important.  In this instance, the direct descendant selector (>) is your friend.  If you require the id component of the rule, just be sure to apply it to both rules.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you very much!  I actually came up with a solution in the meantime, but yours is much better! :D